# By what authority can Wonder Woman perform a marriage?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

Apparently, in a new issue Wonder Woman officiates a marriage. However as a foreign diplomat under what authority does Wonder Woman have to do so?

[image]

Comment: Wonder woman would not legally be recognized as a valid wedding officiater in NYC. She is not a minster or clergy (wo)man as far as the new 52 had shown. Diplomats and Ambassadors do not have special marriage privileges in NYC. And as can clearly be seen, she is performing the ceremony in line of sight of NYC, putting her in the 5 boroughs, so the line about "By the Power vested in me by the ***State*** of NY" is bs since NY state registered ministers have no standing in NYC which has its own rules/laws. Anyone married within nyc limits must follow NYC code.

Comment: She’s Wonder Woman. Are you going to argue?

Comment: She took an online course and paid $20 for a license.

Comment: Even Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson performed marriage. It can't be that difficult for Wonder Woman.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

She says it right there, the State Of New York.  Wonder Woman got licensed to perform marriage in New York state.  She tells Clark after...

> I’m licensed in every state and country that would allow me.

It's not difficult in New York, there are just some hoops.

To perform marriage in New York state (see [Solemnization Of Marriage](http://usmarriagelaws.com/search/united_states/new_york/index.shtml)) the person performing the marriage must register with the appropriate clerk and be any one of...

- Clergy or minister of any religion.
- The leaders of one of several [Societies For Ethical Culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethical_movement).
- Various judges.
- Various clerks.
- Various mayors.

One does *not* need to be a resident of New York.

As a Goddess, Wonder Woman could be considered clergy by New York State. It's Wonder Woman, so the clerk would probably give her some leeway. Or she's a minister in the [Universal Life Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Life_Church) or similar religion who will ordain you and give you the necessary paperwork.

In [New York City it's a bit harder](http://usmarriagelaws.com/search/united_states/new_york/index.shtml).  Simply being ordained a minister isn't enough, you need to show you have a congregation.  I don't know her lore enough to know if she has worshipers and performs ceremonies for them.  If she did, that would be enough.

Answer (score 5):

Keeping it in the USA (since she says it's in New York):

Let's skip Las Vegas, which has a few gazillion wedding chapels with Elvis impersonators and many other unusual wedding officiants, since that basically proves that, in Nevada, it's not but so difficult to get a license to perform weddings.

Wonder Woman's ability or authority to perform a wedding has nothing to do with her diplomatic status or lack thereof.  [Each state has its own laws](http://www.usmarriagelaws.com/search/united_states/officiants_requirements/) about what is required for a person to be able to officiate at a wedding.  Quite often it comes down to having some kind of certificate of ordination and paying a small fee, swearing an oath (or something like that) and then being certified by a court clerk.  (Sometimes this may need to be done in each county or city where one wishes to officiate at a marriage.)

The most specific part of the process is gaining a certificate of ordination, but this can be obtained through the mail or online from many sources, even at least one [Church of the Flying Spaghetti Monster](http://www.venganza.org/ordination/).  All one needs to do is find a group with beliefs they are comfortable with, fill out the forms, and become ordained in their unique little religion.

In New York (since that's the state she's in), requirements don't appear to be too difficult, but she might have to use some paperwork to show she's authorized by a church.

Essentially anyone can gain the qualifications to marry a couple in most states in the USA.


**For those requiring more detail or an example**, In Virginia (good, simple example, plus I live there and know people who have gone through this process), an officiant simply needs to go to a court clerk (I presume for the locality in which the officiant wishes to perform marriages), present the certificate of ordination and $16 and answer some questions.  Then, *poof*, it's official and the person is a able to officiate marriages.  Also note that, in Virginia, one must be a resident of the state to qualify.  (Again, this is just an example, but maybe Wonder Woman could provide some proof of residency if needed.  But non-residents and non-ordained can obtain certificates for one-time-only officiations, so that would mean Wonder Woman could do this.)

Other states, of course, have different laws.  Some will have different residency requirements for the couple getting married, as well.

A certificate of ordination is a tricky thing.  I have friends who can officiate at weddings and have their own faith and, basically, their own church.  I know some who have basically sent in a few dollars to various "churches" and have received the papers that are considered legal.

I know of one example that doesn't fit most "normal" definitions.  I belong to a local Quaker Meeting.  Quakers don't handle many things like other faiths do.  For instance we (at least unprogrammed Quakers) do not believe in ordination and we do not have a specified minister or preacher.  The closest we have to any recognized leader is the Clerk of the Meeting, and that changes every two years.  The Clerk's job is to facilitate and coordinate and handle administrative issues, but not to be a preacher or a leader in the traditional sense.  So every two years we have a new Clerk, and they have to get certified to perform weddings.  I don't know the details, but I know it's a simple process and one done every time we get a new Clerk of Meeting.  They're not ordained (and Quakers do not swear oaths, either).  I don't know what exception is made, but that's proof one does not have to be any kind of local, state, or federal official to perform a wedding, at least in this state, and that even someone without ordination is able to do this.

Comment: Yeah, well, when you finish filling out the forms, the power is vested in you, whether you're a state official or not.

Comment: Can of worms eh? Howzabout this ? By Amazonian laws she can officiate nearly anything she wants but as to who will recognize it...

Comment: I'm not sure, but can't you do a quick civil wedding in NY State for $100.00 bucks? Almost the same as Vegas?

Comment: Speaking of being married by Elvis impersonators, I see a great opportunity for Vegas wedding chapels here.

Comment: Some states also require a letter of good standing in the religion you are ordained in. So for the universal life church, you simply pay a fee and they send you the required letter.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that Themiscyra has it's own Amazonian laws; and that Diana served as Ambassador, it seems feasible. In reality most of the Commonwealth has revoked that privilege.

> Until DC's New 52 relaunch, there were a few other aspects of the origin story that remained consistent. Her mother, Hippolyta, created her out of clay, and the Greek gods bestowed her with life, making her the only Amazon who was not conceived by a man. She grows up among the Amazons who teach her the skills of a warrior as well as the lessons of peace and love. When Steve Trevor, an American pilot, crash lands on Paradise Island, the Amazons have a contest to determine who should receive the honor of taking him back to man's world and acting as an ambassador of all that the Amazons represent.

[Source](http://www.comicvine.com/wonder-woman/4005-2048/)

> In January 1995 the Australian Attorney General revoked all appointments of marriage officers at Australian overseas missions. Therefore consular officers can no longer marry Australians.

[Source](http://bali.indonesia.embassy.gov.au/blli/marriage.html)

Comment: Australian law would not apply to New York state.

Comment: True, but it would be a U.S. Federal decision whether a foreign marriage is recognized. Most Commonwealth countries have gay marriage rights; but they would not be recognized in some American states. Simply saying that as an Amazonian Ambassador she feasibly could officiate a wedding. As to who would recognize it, well depending upon definition there would be 200 different countries laws to run through.

Comment: She says "by the power vested in me by the State of New York", not "by the power of the Amazons" or even "by the power of Greyskull". An ambassador on foreign soil performing a wedding under their own laws would invoke their own country, not the location they're currently standing in. The clincher is the next panel where she tells Clark Kent ["I’m licensed in every state and country that would allow me."](http://funagram.com/wonder-woman-speaks-out-for-marriage-equality-and-educates-clark-kent-in-the-process/)

Comment: Hence my point, Diana can officiate the wedding but there will be plenty of jurisdictions that would not recognize the ceremony; Amazonian or not. I'm touching on the ambasssador role; if done the ceremony was exercised on a consular property then it would be legal under set country's laws. Go Battlecat!!

Comment: Sorry forgot something. Every state...that would allow me. Obviously, a great many would not.

Comment: Which countries does NY recognize Ambassodor foreign weddings? Just curious. We've had one in Canada; Dutch princess; escaping the Nazis. Birth ward of the hospital was declared Dutch territory for the birth of a royal. If I'm wrong please feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: Why would an Amazonian ambassador invoke the power of the State of New York?